# Conditional String Matching in Variable

Tags: python

I am trying to parse emails using python. Sometimes I need to cleanse some of the data to make it fit for purpose. In the example below the first `home_team` returns 'Bristol' and I need to amend this to 'Bristol City'.

I had thought this code would work but it is still returning Bristol. Can anyone see what the issue is?

```
home_team = inc_msg[inc_msg.find(' ')+1 : inc_msg.find(' -')] if inc_msg[inc_msg.find(' ')+1 : inc_msg.find(' -')] else ''
home_team = 'Bristol-City' if home_team == 'Bristol' else home_team.replace(' ', '-')
```

Comment: We have no idea what `inc_msg` is

Comment: We can only say that obviously `home_team` is not `"Bristol"` after the first line if the `if` doesn't match.

Comment: The second line of your code is working fine and as you expect it. The error might be elsewhere in your code. Specify your problem better and include [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the message you are trying to process (the content for `inc_msg`)?

Comment: Don't think we need to know! OP said the first home_team returns Bristol. Are you sure there are no spaces?

Comment: @Andy yes _OP said_ but clearly they have missed something like escaped characters because the second line with the ternary `if` clearly checks if `home_team` equals `"Bristol"` so if it actually were `"Bristol"` then it would make it `"Bristol-City"`

Comment: I suspect something like a line break. if `inc_msg` is `"Team Bristol -"` everything will be fine, if it is `"Team Bristol\n -"` it won't work as intended. I suggest adding a `print(repr(home_team))` in the line before the replacement.

Comment: i think the return is "Bristol " or " Bristol" or " Bristol ", they still have a space, and condition still not match with "Bristol"

Comment: @James if the "Bristol" is unique, you can use in condition, like this => if 'Bristol' in home_team

Comment: you could also try `if home_team.strip() == 'Bristol'` but I would suggest to use `.strip()` on the previous line instead then

Comment: @EkiSaputra If `home_team` is `"Bristol "` (with a trailing space) the space will be replaced with `-` in the second line.

Comment: @Matthias hmmm i think so, but he says "the first home_team returns 'Bristol' and I need to amend this to 'Bristol City'", maybe he need buy a coffee

Comment: @EkiSaputra no they need to provide a [mre] and show what `inc_msg` is (preferably the `repr`esentation of `inc_msg`)

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your check to be case insensitive and also consider that `home_team` could contain other characters that you might not be expecting. One way to do that is by converting `home_team` to lowercase in the second line and use the `in` operator to check if `home_team` variable contains the `'bristol'` string, like this:

```
home_team = inc_msg[inc_msg.find(' ')+1 : inc_msg.find(' -')] if inc_msg[inc_msg.find(' ')+1 : inc_msg.find(' -')] else ''
home_team = 'Bristol-City' if 'bristol' in home_team.lower() else home_team.replace(' ', '-')
```

I find it hard to say what is the actual issue without seeing what's the content of `inc_msg`.

Comment: also you can shorten to `home_team = inc_msg[inc_msg.find(' ') + 1: inc_msg.find(' -')] or ''`, either how it is probably not the best way to slice the string and some other method could (probably should) be used to get the string needed, but sure